# How to display An Image Specified in HTML using Java?

Tags: java, html, image

Hi I've made a simple Webpage in Html. I executed it from Desktop an it works fine. Now i'm in the process of making a Client/Server Program in Eclipse as part of an assessment. I've added my HTML folder (contain html + img), and using a Buffered Reader i can write to Client, but the image appears as a broken link. Any idea on how to resolve this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080); 
    File html = new File("src\\html\\webpage.html");
    String sCurrentLine;    
    System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8080 ....");

    while (true)
    { 
        try (Socket cs = server.accept()){

         String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
         cs.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes());

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(html))) 
            {
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    cs.getOutputStream().write(sCurrentLine.getBytes());
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) 
                {               
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }      
    }               
  } 
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <HTML>
       <HEAD>
          <TITLE>
            This is a Title
          </TITLE>
       </HEAD>
    <BODY>
       <H1>Hello World</H1>
       <P>This is very minimal "hello world"</P>
       <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    <img src="tab_background.png"> 
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to write your own HTTP server. Currently, whatever the request it receives, it always sends back the HTML page. It needs to send back the image, with the appropriate content type, when the browser asks for the image. It seems you don't really understand how HTML and HTTP work yet. Why don't you use one of the many HTTP servers available, instead of reinventing the wheel? Writing an HTTP server is far from being an easy task.

Comment: Tbh all I want to do here is display the contents of the html file via java program. I will be using HTTP for all request later. I'm just confused as to why this code would load the image when I connect to server.. it displays all of the text ,titles, etc but not the image ?

Comment: How could it display the image without loading it from the server? If you use your browser to browse photos at flickr, the browser downloads these photos from flickr, using HTTP, the same way it downloads the HTML pages containing references to these images. It can't just download the HTML and guess what the images would be without downloading them. Since your custom HTTP server doesn't allow downloading the image, the client can't display it.